# Fundamental class of $M\times N$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, orientation

> (Hatcher 3.B.4) Show that the cross product of fundamental classes for closed $R$-orientable manifolds $M$ and $N$ is a fundamental class for $M\times N$. Assume $\dim M = m,\dim N = n$.

Let $[M]$ and $[N]$ be fundamental classes of $M$ and $N$ respectively. Since $M,N$ are closed orientable manifolds, by Kunneth formula,
$$H_{m+n}(M\times N;\Bbb Z)\simeq H_{m}(M;\Bbb Z)\otimes H_n(N;\Bbb Z)$$
and this isomorphism is given by (homology) cross product. Hence, $[M]\times [N]$ is a generator of $H_{m+n}(M\times N;\Bbb Z)$. Now I need to check if $H_{m+n}(M\times N;\Bbb Z)\to H_{m+n}(M\times N-\{(x,y)\};\Bbb Z)$ maps $[M]\times[N]\to \mu_{(x,y)}$ where $\mu_{(x,y)}$ is a local orientation of $M\times N$.

But btw, what is a local orientation of $M\times N$? Can I express it as local orientations of $M$ and $N$? I have no idea how to proceed further. Could you help?

Note. One might remind Hatcher exercise 3.3.5 ($M\times N$ is orientable if and only if $M$ and $N$ are both orientable). I don't know the proof using direct argument using definition (I think it's quite complicated) but I know the proof using orientable cover which does not give local orientation of $M\times N$ (I remember there is a post asking this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Theorem 1:*** Let $A\subseteq_\text{open} X,\ B\subseteq_\text{open} Y$. Consider the realtive chain complexes $\mathcal C=C_*(X,A)$ and $\mathcal C'=C_*(Y,B)$. Then there is a natural split short exact sequence  $$0\to \bigoplus_{p+q=n}H_p(X,A)\otimes H_q(Y,B)\xrightarrow{\text{cross product}} H_n(X\times Y,A\times Y\cup X\times B)\to \bigoplus_{p+q=n-1}\text{Tor}\big(H_p(X,A),H_q(Y,B)\big)\to 0$$

---

***Theorem 2:*** For a manifold $X$ of dimension $d$ and $x\in X\backslash \partial X$ we have $H_n(X,X\backslash x)=\begin{cases} \Bbb Z &\text{ if }n=d,\\ 0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$

*Proof:* Use excision theorem considering a closed coordinate ball $\overline B\cong \{z\in \Bbb R^d:|z|\leq 1\}$ with $x\in \text{int}(\overline B)$.

---

***Corollary 1:*** For two manifolds $M,\ \dim M=m$ and $N,\ \dim N=n$ with $x\in M\backslash \partial M,\ y\in N\backslash \partial N$ we have the isomorphism $$H_m(M,M\backslash x)\otimes H_n(N, N\backslash y)\xrightarrow[\cong]{\text{cross product}} H_{m+n}\big(M\times N,M\times N\backslash (x,y)\big)$$

*Proof:* Combine Theorem 1 and Theorem 2.

---

***Observation 1:*** For two manifolds $M,\ \dim M=m$ and $N,\ \dim N=n$ with $x\in M\backslash \partial M,\ y\in N\backslash \partial N$ and orientations $\{\mu_p:p\in M\backslash \partial M\},\ \{\nu_q:q\in N\backslash \partial N\}$ we have the following commutative diagram

[image]

where as usual $x\in U\subseteq_\text{open}M$ and $\mu_U\in H_m(M, M\backslash U)\cong \Bbb Z$ is a generator such that $\mu_U\longmapsto \mu_p$ for each $p\in U$ under the inclusion induced map $H_m(M,M\backslash U)\to H_m(M,M\backslash p)$. Similarly, define $\nu_V$.

The bottom arrow is an isomorphism due to *Corollary 1.* A similar reasoning(cross-product argument) says the top arrow is also an isomorphism. The left arrow is an isomorphism due to the choice of $U$ and $V$ while defining orientations. Now, the commutativity of the square implies, the right arrow is an isomorphism.

> In other words,  $\{\mu_p\times \nu_q: p\in M\backslash \partial M,
>  q\in N\backslash \partial N\}$ defines an orientation for $M\times N$.

---

***Theorem 3:*** Let $M,N$ be two compact oriented manifolds with the fundamental classes $[M]\in H_m(M,\partial M),\ [N]\in H_n(N,\partial N)$.

Then, the fundamental class $[M\times N]\in H_{m+n}\big(M\times N, \partial(M\times N)\big)$ is same as the $[M]\times [N]$.

*Proof:* Consider $x\in M\backslash \partial M, y\in N\backslash \partial N$, then $(x,y)\in M\times N\backslash \partial(M\times N)$. So, the inclusion induce map $H_{m+n}\big(M\times N,\partial(M\times N)\big)\longrightarrow H_{m+n} \big(M \times N, M \times N \backslash (x, y)\big)$ is an isomorphism. Now, consider the commutative diagram below.

[image]

The bottom arrow is an isomorphism due to *Corollary 1.* The left arrow is isomorphism as $x\in \text{int}(M),\ y\in \text{int}(N)$. So, the top arrow is an isomorphism, i.e., the cross product map $H_m (M, \partial M ) \otimes  H_n (N, \partial N )\xrightarrow{\times}H_{m+n} \big(M \times N, \partial(M \times N )\big)$ sends $[M]\otimes [N]$ to $[M\times N]$.

Comment: My assumption is that both manifolds are *closed* but it seems I can drop that condition.

Comment: Yup, I have written the answer as generally as possible.

Comment: Quoting the Künneth theorem is somewhat overkill. By excision, as in Theorem 2, you really only have to know the cross product gives an isomorphism $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})\otimes H_m(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\})\rightarrow H_{m+n}(\mathbb{R}^{m+n},\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\setminus\{0\})$. This is completely explicit and sometimes even used as lemma in proving a more general Künneth theorem.

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible, and the easiest one also. But, I have not given much time to think, a moment thought plus standard theorem input-output.